# Laravel trying to redirect for all jquery ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, redirect, laravel-5.5

Whenever i try to do some ajax calls in the page, it works good in localhost but in the live its throwing error like this

[image]

Though i have did this in `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
     //return redirect('admin/dashboard');
}
```

Pls help me with this

Answer (score 3):

i hope that following code you put in JS file and elsewhere in meta of the page. for Ajax calling.

## ==========================================

**In JS File write 
$(document).ready(function () {...}**

==========================================

```
      $.ajaxSetup(
        {
           headers:
            {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
            }
        });
```

It also verify AJAX call while Request and Response.

Answer (score 0):

**[this is a browser-ajax-CORS problem](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)**

> **solution1: the [laravle-enable-cors-composer-package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) into your project**
>
> **solution2: add following line into your ajax-controller-method**

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }
```

> solution3: [config the appache](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) [nginx](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)